# Laurent series to converge in $0<|z-1|<R$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

**Question:**

Determine the largest number $R$ so that the Laurent series of $$f(z)=\frac2{z^2-1} + \frac3{2z-i}$$ about $z=1$ converges for $0<|z-1|<R$.

**Attempt:**

I really don't understand this question. The singularities are $\pm 1, i/2$. The point $1$ doesn't lie in the region given. If $R$ was such that $-1$ would be a boundary point on the circle, $R=2$. And if $R$ was such that $i/2$ would be a boundary point on the circle, $R=\sqrt5/2$. Both can't be a boundary point but the largest $R$ is $2$ so would that simply be the answer?

I don't see how this would make the series converge either. I really don't understand this question!

Comment: If the Laurent series converges in an annulus $r < \lvert z-a\rvert < R$, its sum function is holomorphic in that annulus.

Comment: @DanielFischer So if I make my $R=\sqrt5/2$, then everything would be holomorphic right? Because then the point 1 and -1 wont lie in the region and the circle would be almost touching the point i/2. Right?

Comment: Right. And if you try $R = 2$, how does $f$ behave in the annulus $0 < \lvert z-1\rvert < 2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer There would be a singularity at $z=i/2$?, meaning it is not holomorphic at that point.

Comment: @DanielFischer meaning it would diverge (or not converge) at $i/2$?

Comment: Exactly, I elaborated a bit more in my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the largest number for which a Laurent Series converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290207/find-the-largest-number-for-which-a-laurent-series-converges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two facts about Laurent series are important here:

1. If $h$ is holomorphic in an annulus $r < \lvert z-a\rvert < R$, then there is a Laurent series $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n$$ converging to $h$ in that annulus, and
2. the sum function of a Laurent series is holomorphic in its annulus of convergence, i.e. if $$s(z) := \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n$$ converges for $r < \lvert z-a\rvert < R$, then $s$ is holomorphic in the annulus $r < \lvert z-a\rvert < R$.

In our case, where the inner radius of the annulus is $0$, that means the outer radius of the annulus is the distance to the closest singularity to the centre of the Laurent series.

The two singularities of $f$ other than $1$ are the poles at $-1$ and $\frac{i}{2}$. Since $\frac{i}{2}$ is closer to $1$ than $-1$ is, we have

$$R = \biggl\lvert \frac{i}{2} - 1\biggr\rvert = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2},$$

as you found in the comments.